# Whats the meaning of the Hearthstone terms "If you have" and "If you control"

Tags: hearthstone

Just played after a long time, and I saw that some cards go like "If you have X, then Y" or "if you control X, then Y" where X is a card class like "Mech" or "Beast".
What do these terms mean exactly?

Answer (score 5):

The "if you have" wording in terms of "if you have a beast" means that the battlecry / secondary spell effect only triggers if one of your minions on the board is a beast.

The "if you control" terminology is only seen in terms of beast/mech in the newest adventure, the League of Explorers. It works identically to the "if you have" wording. This is one of many examples of inconsistent wording between Hearthstone cards that work identically.

[image: Fossilized Devilsaur]

[image: Ram Wrangler]

Comment: To clarify, "if you have", refers to minions summoned in the field already, right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I believe this misunderstanding is the reason why they went for another wording.

Comment: It confused me for a while that "if you have" / "if you control" cards require minions on the board, but "if you're holding" cards require minions in the hand.

Comment: If they want to improve why not just change for all cards isntead change for the newest version? I mean this is not physical card game where reprints would be required....

Comment: I agree, but so far I dont believe they have made any card updates except in the case of nerfs.

Comment: Actually, just realized that "if you control" can refer to other things besides minions as well, for example, secrets. E.g. [Ethereal Arcanist](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ethereal_Arcanist)